# Conditional Date with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm still trying my best to understand the syntax of Jquery. I was almost certain I had the following script correct, however the alert I am trying to show (If the day is Monday), appears regardless of the condition. Any help is very appreciated. To recap, I want this alert to appear automatically if the day is equal to Monday.

```
<script>

var mon = new Date().getDay();
if ( mon = 2 ) {

$(document).ready( function () {

alertify.alert("Example Message");
}); 
} else {

}

</script>
```

**Note:** Using the script above still shows the message even though (I believe) Tuesday = 2.

Comment: `mon = 2` assigns the value 2 to the variable "mon"; you probably want `mon == 1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it takes `==` for comparison
`=` is for attribution

```
<script>

var mon = new Date().getDay();
if ( mon == 2 ) {

$(document).ready( function () {

alertify.alert("Example Message");
}); 
} else {

}

</script>
```

`mon = 2` will assign the value 2 to the variable mon. `mon == 2` will verify if mon equals 2

Comment: Thank you for your response, I'm going to mark this as accepted when the time limit is over. To clarify, what I wrote originally could be seen as: "If the value of mon is set to 2 then", compared to what I want which is: "If the value of mon is equal to 2". Am I correct?